# How to pass more than one parameter to jdbcTemplate.update SQL procedure call in Spring Boot

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have one procedure to call for update the database, for which I have to pass two parameters. Below is my code. but I am getting below error

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [call usp_updtateDB(?,?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

```
String currDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    log.info("params:"+Integer.toString(p.getId())+" Date:"+currDate);

     SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("id",Integer.toString(p.getId())).addValue("start_date",currDate);    
                final String sql = "call usp_updtateDB(:id,:start_date)";           
                    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
```

Comment: Are you using an instance of `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning its NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. I have updated the error and the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Message> getMessages(String apiRef, Integer languageId) throws SQLException {

        final String query = "select * from \"FncGetMessage\"(:p_apiref, :p_languageid)";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("p_apiref", apiRef);
        params.put("p_languageid", languageId);

        List<Message> messages = jdbcTemplate.query(query, params, (rs, rowNum) -> new Message(

                rs.getInt("messageid"), rs.getString("apiref"), rs.getString("messageref"), rs.getString("messagetext"),
                rs.getString("messagetype"), rs.getInt("languageid")));

        return messages;

    }
```

I have written `select * from \"FncGetMessage\"(:p_apiref, :p_languageid)` because I have used postgreSQL, Please use correct syntax as your database has